# Add padding to Eclipse terminal

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse version 2022-03 (4.23.0) the terminal requires padding on left hand side. It's annoying. Is there a way to pad it out?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2022-03 on Windows 10. The cropped screenshot does not show if there is a horizontal scrollbar that might cause this. It is annoying and not helpful to read that it is annoying. What does it look like in a fresh Eclipse (without additional plugins) and with a fresh workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the location if not change the Version of eclipse